# Rxjs - TypeError: prop.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to learn rxjs and I'm also a beginner when it comes to Javascript. Right now I'm working on an app and trying to fetching data from firebase's API. The problem is when I try to using the array.map method inside an map operator from rxjs, I get this error:

> TypeError: recipes.map is not a function
> at MapSubscriber.project (data-storage.service.ts:34)

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Recipe } from '../recipes/recipe.model';
import { RecipeService } from '../recipes/recipe.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DataStorageService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private recipeService: RecipeService,
  ) {}
     
  fetchRecipes() {
    return this.http
      .get<Recipe[]>(
        'https://ng-course-recipe-book-m-course.firebaseio.com/recipes.json'
      )
      .pipe(
        map((recipes: Recipe[]) => {
          return (recipes as Array<Recipe>).map((recipe : Recipe) => ({
            ...recipe,
            ingredients: recipe.ingredients ? recipe.ingredients : []
          }));
        }),
        tap(recipes => {
          this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

This is my Recipe model and Ingredient model:

```
import { Ingredient } from '../shared/ingredient.model';

export class Recipe {
  public name: string;
  public description: string;
  public imagePath: string;
  public ingredients: Ingredient[];

  constructor(name: string, desc: string, imagePath: string, ingredients: Ingredient[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
  }
}


export class Ingredient {
  constructor(public name: string, public amount: number) {}
}
```

Am i missing something here?

Edit: This is my log when I doesn't use rxjs:

```
    {0: {…}, 1: {…}, -MAWqHHeK1itiBcD83K0: Array(2)}
0: {description: "A super-tasty Schnitzel - just awesome!", imagePath: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Schnitzel.JPG", ingredients: Array(2), name: "Tasty Schnitzel"}
1: {description: "What else you need to say?", imagePath: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b…rger_King_Angus_Bacon_%26_Cheese_Steak_Burger.jpg", ingredients: Array(4), name: "Big Fat Burger"}
-MAWqHHeK1itiBcD83K0: Array(2)
0: {description: "A super-tasty Schnitzel - just awesome!", imagePath: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Schnitzel.JPG", ingredients: Array(2), name: "Tasty Schnitzel"}
1: {description: "What else you need to say?", imagePath: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b…rger_King_Angus_Bacon_%26_Cheese_Steak_Burger.jpg", ingredients: Array(4), name: "Big Fat Burger"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Log the response to console and make sure you are receiving an Array from the API.

Comment: @esnezz I logged the response data to console and it did give me an array from the API.

Comment: @bubbles here is my log:

Comment: @bubbles I updated my post above, sorry for my inconvenience..

Comment: the log above is the JSON of the response 'ng-course-recipe-book-m-course.firebaseio.com/recipes.json' @bubbles

Comment: What is MAWqHHeK1itiBcD83K0

Comment: Oh, I just check my data in server and found there is one more "sub-folder" called "MAWqHHeK1itiBcD83K0" which has the same data as my "recipes", after I deleted it the code is now working fine.
Thanks AakashGarg and bubbles

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code to :-

```
fetchRecipes() {
    return this.http
      .get(
        'https://ng-course-recipe-book-m-course.firebaseio.com/recipes.json'
      )
      .pipe(
        map((recipes: Recipe[]) => {
          return recipes.map((recipe : Recipe) => ({
            ...recipe,
            ingredients: recipe.ingredients ? recipe.ingredients : []
          }));
        }),
        tap(recipes => {
          this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: the error is still the same as before. It doesn't recognize the prop.array.